# UICollectionView - scroll to the next page

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is there any chance to scroll in the UICollectionView to the wanted item using . scrollToItemAtIndexPath and snap not to the item itself, but to the page the item is part of? (I got paging enabled.)

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by page of the item?

Comment: Does each page have fixed number of collection cells?

Comment: Yup, the page of the item. I have pages displaying particular month (it's a calendar). But (almost) every month starts with different day (friday, monday etc.) and I want to scroll to the section(month) that contains current day. So if I want to scroll to (let's say it is now 14th of December 2015) it displays it like this: https://imgur.com/TiDWW8X -- that's why I want to snap it to current page/section

Answer (score 9):

You need to create `NSIndexPath` than scroll to that index.

```
 //Mark: - Move to cell when view did appear

overload viewDidAppear() {


    let scrollIndex: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: dayIndex, inSection: monthSection)
    if (// Check you are in range of UIcollectionView's count) {
        //Scroll collectionview according to your requirement i.e UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally or UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Left 
        self.YourCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(scrollIndex, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a comment above about the project

Comment: But the thing is it does not snap to the page. It does scroll to the cell itself and that's good, but for cells located in the center of the page (section) I get the view: imgur.com/TiDWW8X.  Also, I don't knwo if it's important, but I don't want this to happen after the click, I want it to happen when you load the view - so I'm trying to implement this .scrollToItemAtIndexPath in viewDidAppear

Comment: Update the answer for viewDidAppear. I am not getting your point about "does not snap to page". There are no pages in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

I did end up using offsetContent property;

I knew the width of every so called page.

1. I wrote a code to get the indexPath for current day
2. I retrieved the section of the indexPath
3. I multiplied the section by the width of the view and named it "offset"
4. I set my UICollectionView.contentOffset.x to "offset" and it works fine.

I also tried using .scrollRectToVisible and the offset, and it worked amazingly, but I also wanted to updated something that was based on the contentOffset of the UICollectionView, and the .scrollRectToVisible seems not to update this property - it was updated only after I dragged the view a little.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Can you please show your code ? I have similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673446/uicollectionview-offscreen-auto-scroll-for-paging