# Paging a CollectionView horizontally by section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How do you set up a collectionView to page horizontally by SECTION much like the native emoji keyboard on iPhone?

So I want the sections to scroll vertically which is working fine, but then if the user swipes the screen left they page to the next SECTION of the collectionView

Also in the toolbar below the collectionView I want the buttons when tapped to take the user to the particular section of the collectionView too. And if the user swipes left to a new SECTION the corresponding button in the toolbar under the collection view highlights also.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionView - scroll to the next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849248/uicollectionview-scroll-to-the-next-page)

Comment: You could also use a UIPageViewController.  This would be a collection of ViewControllers that the user can swipe left and right through, it would also give you a UIElement at the bottom of the screen that the user can use to switch 'sections'. You would then just either create a collectinoView/tableView for each of the VC's for your sections.

Answer (score -1):

Use this option:

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

Note that the size of each page is the size of frame which you set as the frame of collectionView