# UICollectionView : Offscreen auto scroll for paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to scroll `UICollectionView` which is offscreen in my app, by below code.

```
int pages = ceil(aCollectionView.contentSize.height / aCollectionView.frame.size.height);

for (int i = 0; i < pages; i ++)
{
     NSArray *sortedVisibleItems = [[aCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

     NSIndexPath *lastItem = [sortedVisibleItems lastObject];

     // 2.next position
     NSInteger nextItem = lastItem.item + 1;
     NSInteger nextSection = lastItem.section;
     NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:nextItem inSection:nextSection];

     [self takeImage];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {            
        [aCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
    });
}
```

And taking screen shots of each page for printing purpose. 
But its not scrolling and always prints the 1st page multiple times.

UICollectionView's property

[image]

Am I missing or doing in wrong direction ?

Answer (score 0):

You are always getting last object by `NSIndexPath *lastItem = [sortedVisibleItems lastObject]`; to take a image. This will only capture same page always.

This is because you are not removing lastObject from your array.

Remove your lastObject by using

```
[sortedVisibleItems removeLastObject];
```

Comment: No, that array is for visible indexes. So last object means last visible index in the page so I can add 1 and move to next cell of next page.

Answer (score 0):

```
int pages = ceil(aCollectionView.contentSize.height / aCollectionView.frame.size.height);
NSArray *visibleItems = [aCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
NSInteger row = 0;
NSIndexPath *currentItem;
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visibleItems) {
    if (row < indexPath.row){
        row = indexPath.row;
        currentItem = indexPath;
    }
}
NSLog(@"current indexpath ; %ld",(long)currentItem.row);
if (currentItem.row == pages-1) {
    return;
}
NSIndexPath *nextItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:currentItem.item + 1 inSection:currentItem.section];
[aCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:YES];
```

Try this

Comment: What problem is you getting?

Answer (score 0):

A collection view only updates on the main thread. Your code is wrapped in a loop, which never allows the main thread to run and update.

There are lots of discussions about this out there. Many related directly to doing the same thing with `UIScrollView`, but it's the same issue.

You might want to look at this... not sure if it will fit your needs, but I've seen it referenced multiple times: https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/PDFGenerator

If that doesn't work for you, it probably has the technique you need in it, so a little investigating of that code should find your answer.

Comment: I have also tried with
 ` dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {            
            [aCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
        });
`
check my updated Question

Comment: Again, that won't work, because you are blocking the main thread in your loop. So now, each time through you are telling iOS: *"scroll the collection view, but wait for the main thread before you do it... but go ahead and `[self takeImage]` now"*. Here's another link for you - this one is Obj-C, and is more straight-forward (fewer options): https://github.com/azu/ScrollViewToPDF